# Computations with canonical sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider $X=\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$ and two projections $p,q:X\to\mathbb{P}^1$. It is known that $\omega_X\cong p^*\omega_{\mathbb{P}^1}\otimes q^*\omega_{\mathbb{P}^1}$.

How can I compute cohomologies $H^i(\mathbb{P}^1, (p_*\omega_X)(1))$?

Is it possible to compute $p_*\omega_X$ explicitly (i.e., to split it into the direct sum of line bundles over $\mathbb{P}^1$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact $p_*\omega_X= 0$.

**Basic fact**: $\omega_{\mathbb{P}^1} = \mathcal{O}(-2)$ does not have global sections.

By definition stalk of $p_* \omega_X$ at $x$ equals the direct limit of global sections of preimages of neighbour of $x$ (limit is taking over neighborhoods). But all these global sections are 0 as far as they are 0 at each fiber (follows from the basic fact). If all stalks of a sheaf are 0 then the sheaf itself is 0.